# How to read Boolean values from RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

For my `RecyclerView`, how can I use the `Boolean` values declared in the `Fragment` to show or hide various items in my `RecyclerView` item template? In my adapter class, I tried using e.g. `holder.mIVLanguage.visibility = (myList[position].displaySymbolLanguage)` but that didn't work.

[image]

**RecyclerView item data class**

```
data class Facility (val arrowExpandCollapse: Drawable,
                       val topicSymbol: Drawable,
                       val displaySymbolLanguage: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolPets: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolVerifiedUser: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolTransport: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolSeating: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolFingerPrint: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolArrival: Boolean,
                       val displaySymbolDeparture: Boolean)
```

**RecyclerView fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

        val symbolsArray = intArrayOf(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_language_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_pets_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_language_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_pets_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_language_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_pets_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_language_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_pets_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_pets_black_24dp)

        val myList = ArrayList<Facility>()
                     myList.add(Facility(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down, null),
                            resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp, null), true, false, false, false, true, true, true, false))
            }
        }

        val mAdapter = RVAdapterFacilities(myList)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView adapter class**

```
class RVAdapterFacilities(val myList: ArrayList<Facility>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterFacilities.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {      
        holder.mIVExpandCollapse.setImageDrawable(myList[position].arrowExpandCollapse)

        holder.mIVTopic.setImageDrawable(myList[position].topicSymbolol)

        holder.mIVLanguage.visibility = ¿What goes here?                  
        holder.mIVPets.visibility = ¿What goes here?
        holder.mIVVerifiedUser.visibility = ¿What goes here?                  
        holder.mIVTransport.visibility = ¿What goes here?
        holder.mIVSeat.visibility = ¿What goes here?                  
        holder.mIVFingerprint.visibility = ¿What goes here?
        holder.mIVDeparture.visibility = ¿What goes here?                  
        holder.mIVArrival.visibility = ¿What goes here?
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cv_facility_information, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val mCV = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cv_facilities)
        val mIVExpandCollapse = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_expandcollapsearrow)!!
        val mIVTopic = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_topicsymbol)!!
        val mLLSymbols = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_symbols)!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Visibility requires an int, not a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you can use to set the visibility of a view are `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE` and `GONE`. In your case you would probably want to set `VISIBLE` or `GONE` based on the boolean value:

```
holder.mIVLanguage.visibility = if (myList[position].displaySymbolLanguage) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

Comment: @MacaronLover I just rolled back your edit. While `when` expressions are pretty great, using them on boolean values is overly verbose and won't yield any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, Visibility requires an int, not a boolean.

You can simply check the value of `(myList[position].displaySymbolLanguage)` and decide whether to make `mIVLanguage` View.VISIBLE or View.GONE. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
holder.mIVLanguage.visibility = if(myList[position].displaySymbolLanguage) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!